# Common shared CSS JS files in a directory shared between similar sites?

Tags: css, shared, web-architecture, shared-file

Backgournd info: 
I have a ISS6 webserver hosting multiple websites. I have about 15 domains that could be considered "sister" sites that share styles, layouts, etc but they still will have their own customization styles. (I haven't created anything but these basic sites just yet)

The question is thus: **since a good portion of the CSS and JS for each site will be the same, what are some ways to share a common master CSS & JS directory between sites on the same IIS server?**

I know I could host this master directory of common files on one of the domains and  it from there but that doesn't seem like the most elegant option. Or I could give each domain its own personal copy of the CSS and JS files as well which probably the worst option.

I do not use any version control software or Visual Studio, just notepad++ so I'm not so concerned with sharing files among developers.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 2):

For historical record, I'd recommend that you infact DO host your shared files on a single, separate domain. Especially if that is all that domain is used for.

The primary benefit is that the domain will be cookieless (reducing bulk in each HTTP call). It's one step down from the optimum solution which would be to host your shared files on a CDN. Amazon's S3/CloudFront solution is very affordable.